# How to protect host fabric stability in Hyper-V under high load

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

We have a server, running Windows Server 2016 with 4 physical cores (8 hyperthreads) and has Hyper-V installed.

Now, let's say that there are two VMs, each configured in Hyper-V to have a certain number of cores X.  Let's say that each of those VMs is under very high load - 80% to 100% CPU load.

If I want to safely preserve a margin for the host to stay healthy so that I can remote desktop to the server to manage it, what is the maximum number of cores I can assign to each VM in Hyper-V?  Do I need to leave one core "free" so that the host stays stable/accessible?  If so, can I leave a partial core free instead of a whole core?

Is there a separate setting to specify how much CPU should be preserved for the host machine?

Also, in Hyper-V does one core mean one physical core (of which there are 4 in this example) or one logical core (of which there are 8 in this example)?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to leave one core "free" so that the host stays stable/accessible?

No. See, the "host" is a VM. And that particular master VM has a higher priority than any other VM's.

> If so, can I leave a partial core free instead of a whole core?

Given that assigned core counts are all INTEGER, how would you even ENTER a non integer number?

Comment: OK got it - so basically you are saying Microsoft has taken care of this already and assigned a higher priority - this is not something I need to manually configure, is that right?  Re: your second question: In Docker you can assign less than one core so I thought maybe Hyper-V could do less than one as well.

Comment: Exactly. THis is one reason NOTHING (except backup, measurement etc.) should ever be installed on a hyper-v server... it runs with higher priority and can starve the VM's.